# Error during initialization of VM on fresh eclipse/Java install

Tags: java, eclipse, path, compilation, virtual-machine

I've just installed the JDK 9 and eclipse-java Photon (the .rar that you can download from their webpage).

1. Opened eclipse for the first time + Set the workspace.
2. Configured some visual things.
3. Created an empty project (some test package -> some test Class).
4. Tried to run it (a 100% EMPTY Class, just an empty main() and that's it).
5. [**Got this error**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdjWj.png) (the *'D:\Boludeces'* displayed path is not at all related with any installation of eclipse nor JDK/JRE. That's confuses me).

I'm not sure what's wrong here. I'm using Windows 7 64-bits. Software versions (both of JDK/JRE and eclipse) are 64-bits also (completely sure about that), so they should be complatible with each other.
The *Run configuration* is also completely untouched.
Those are my installation paths:

eclipse: `D:\Boludeces ^_^\Programas\Carpetas de programas\eclipse\java-photon`.

eclipse's default workspace: `D:\Boludeces ^_^\Programas\Carpetas de programas\eclipse\Workspace`.

JDK: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1`.

JRE: `C:\Program Files\Java\jre-9.0.1`.

Some useful pictures below:

1 [CLASSPATH environment variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTjhU.png)

2 [PATH environment variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLzQ2.png)

3 [Other Java's environment variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwAKg.png)

2 [*java -version* on *cmd*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXSmU.png)

Do somebody has any ideas? Thanks in advance. Best regards,

*Viciecal*

Comment: Eclipse Photon has not yet released and for Windows you can download it as `.zip` not as `.rar`. Could you please tell from where (URL) and what you downloaded?

Comment: Hello, I can't get to the link in question right now, but it's just a normal eclipse - The splash screen says "eclipse Photon, June 2018". Anyways, I'm downloading Oxygen ATM, to see if that can solve my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Here you can download an Eclipse IDE package of the current release (Oxygen.1a): http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/

Comment: I downloaded that package and the problem was solved... Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse **Photon** will be released on [June 27, 2018](https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=NWI2cXM4MHFzc2IzbHRvYWZhMjVmajJnbzkgZ2NoczdubTRudnBtODM3NDY5ZGRqOXRqbGtAZw). There are currently only [milestones pre-releases](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/index-developer.php) of Eclipse Photon which **might be unstable**.

If you have problems, you can **use** an [Eclipse IDE package of the **current release**](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/) (which is currently Oxygen.1a) instead.